# Nuxt middleware infinite redirect issue

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Hello I am trying to execute this middleware in my Nuxt 3 app. I am trying to follow the documentation and I am getting infinite redirect error.

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    
   const user = {
        id: 1,
        name: "James"
    };

    if (process.server) {
        if (user.id === 1){
        console.log('confirmed');
        navigateTo( '/about' );
    }
        return
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because both `process.server` and `user.id === 1` always evaluate to true.

You can avoid the infinite redirect with:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {

  const user = { id: 1, name: "James" };
  
  if (process.server) {
      if (user.id === 1 && to.path !== '/about'){
      console.log('confirmed');
      return navigateTo( '/about' );
    }
  }
})
```