# infinite redirect issue in nuxt 3 global middleware using from.name

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I need help to understand the use of the `from` argument in the `defineNuxtRouteMiddleware` function in a Nuxt 3 project.

I have a Nuxt 3 project with this structure:

```
pages
  index.vue
  new.vue
```

I have a global middleware to redirect from the home to a new page.

This code create an infinite redirect issue:

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {

  if (from.name === 'index') {

    return navigateTo({
      path: `/new`, 
      redirectCode: 301 
    });
  }
})
```

What is the reason? In my understanding, the `from.name` is `index` at the first request to the homepage, but on the next request it should be `new` and the redirect skipped.

I resolved with this code, adding a `to.path !== '/new'` condition:

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {

  if (from.name === 'index' && to.path !== '/new') {

    return navigateTo({
      path: `/new`, 
      redirectCode: 301 
    });
  }
})
```

Is this the correct solution to my problem?

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76121805/nuxt-middleware-infinite-redirect-issue) that I answered myself because in that case it's quite obvious that the if statement always evaluate to true on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used, adding `to.path !== '/new' that I fought was a workaround, Is actually the suggested solution in the middleware [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware#format):

> In a real app you would probably not redirect every route to `/`
> however it is important to check `to.path` before redirecting or you
> might get an infinite redirect loop
>
> ```
> if (to.path !== '/') {  
>   return navigateTo('/')  
> }
> ```

So, that is the proper way to avoid the infinite redirect loop. There isn't a better solution.

It's still unclear to me why `from.name === 'index'` it's not enough, but that is another story.
`