# Infinite redirect in navigation guard

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

```
import nuxtStorage from 'nuxt-storage';

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to , from , next ) => {
     const authentication = nuxtStorage.localStorage.getData('authentication')
             if(authentication === true){ 
                   return  navigateTo('/admin')
             }
     return   navigateTo('/')     
})
```

when i create a middleware, somedata stored in localstorage key is authentication and value is true.
if i checking condition if it is true navigate to admin page otherwise navigate to home.but i get error 'infinite redirect in navigation guard'.

how rewrite the code

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the infinite redirect loop, you need something to stop it when it is executed the first time, otherwise it will always evaluate to true and will try to redirect from `/admin` to `/admin` or from `/` to `/` forever.

A simple solution could be:

```js
 if(authentication && to.path !== '/admin'){ 
   return navigateTo('/admin')
 }
 else if (!authentication && to.path !== '/'){
   return navigateTo('/')  
 }
 return
```

Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76121805/11258206) question.